# How to start the Node.JS server from PHP?

Tags: php, node.js

I have installed Node.JS and it is working fine.  But I am wondering on how I can start the server from PHP (assuming I have full control since I'm on `localhost`).

I made a batch script that I use to start Node from Command Prompt:

```batch
:: nodejs.bat

@ECHO OFF
CD %NodeJS
:: The above is my NodeJS directory

CLS
TITLE Running Node Server %1.js
ECHO Starting Server...
nodemon --trace-warnings --quiet %1.js
```

I start it from the command prompt as:

```
nodejs path/to/my/current/project
```

`nodejs.bat` is located at `%userprofile%\nodejs.bat`, so this is how I try starting my program in PHP:

```php
$cmd="%userprofile%\\nodejs.bat ".$_POST["s"];

echo $cmd; // Just for debugging purposes

exec($cmd);
```

The above didn't work for me.  Does anyone know of a way to start the Node.JS server from PHP?

Extra details:

- I don't want to run a Node.JS file, I just want to start a server
- I don't *have* to use `nodejs.bat`, it's just easier to type compared to `nodemon --trace-warnings --quiet [my file path]`

If you need any more details, please ask in the comments and I will add them.

Comment: Why do you need node and PHP on the same server? They basically do the same job

Comment: I don't *need* them on the same server.  I usually used PHP, but I'm learning Node.JS too.  I just want to **start** Node *from* PHP (if that is possible).

Comment: Ok. So did you take the output of `echo $cmd` and check if it works from the regular command line on the same machine?

Comment: @ADyson: Sorry for replying a bit late. Yes, when I copy pasted the output, and put it in cmd, then it started the server.

Comment: How are you serving PHP? With IIS, it Apache perhaps? It's likely that it's running under a different user account than the one you use to login. Therefore the userprofile folder will be different.

Comment: You should probably capture the output from exec to try and get more details - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @ADyson: Hmmm.... I'll try to see what's happening.

Comment: @ADyson: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230905/discussion-between-lakshya-raj-and-adyson).

Comment: "Starting node from php" is a anti-patern and should be avoided. There is no logical reason to start node from php. If you realy want to, exec from php `node ...`

Comment: @Marc: I tried what you said, and `node` worked!  There's just one problem: I wanted it to run `nodemon`, although that says in `error.log` that the command doesn't exist... although I can run it through the command line

Comment: @LakshyaRaj I don't quite understand you. Did you install nodemon via npm? (`npm install -g nodemon`) It could be possible that you have a problem with your "Working Directory". Try to "chdir" (not sure if php hase a function for that) into your node.js app directory and run then via php exec `nodemon ...` (Basicly the same as for "node" but only with "nodemon" & a "chdir" befor.

Comment: @Marc: I already have nodemon installed (and I installed it with `npm install -g nodemon`) and I am able to run my `nodejs.bat` (which uses nodemon) from the command line.  But from PHP it says that `nodemon` isn't found.  If I run `where nodemon` on cmd I get `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd`.  I already tried replacing `nodemon` with `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd` in my `nodejs.bat` but it still outputs the same error.

Comment: Im not quite sure, but i think you have to add nodemon to your "PATH" environment variable or use the full path. Since nodemon is installed in your users homedirectory and not "global" on your C:\ drive, this could be a problem. BTW: node & php on Windows is a nightmare. (just my 2 cents)

Comment: @Marc: Hmmm... what path do I add to the path?  I can see the `%appdata%/npm` folder has `nodemon.cmd`, and `%appdata/npm/node_modules/nodemon/` also exists.  Can you specify which one I should add?

Comment: In the Terminal (or when you use Windows "CMD"/PowerShell) you can only run executable files. Which is a `*.cmd`. Add to your "PATH" env, the path to the `nodemon.cmd` file.

Comment: @Marc: I added `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd` to the system PATH variable, but it still doesn't work.  Also, let's [continue this discussion in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230948/).

Comment: I dont can help you with Windows questions. But thats what nearly every OS does when you type "<command>" in the terminal. Look up a env variable and search for a executable with the name of <command>. And in windows its "PATH".

Comment: @Marc: OK, I'll try to do this part myself (doesn't seem *way* too hard).  But thanks for all of the help you gave otherwise!